# Menu rising from bottom of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been searching for a way to make a menu rise up from a menu bar underneath an image

[image]

I want it so when you click on an arrow the menu will open up and partly cover the image without affecting the position of other elements in the page.

I'm struggling to find a way to do this. The reason for posting in here is not for a complete solution but thought that maybe someone could point me in the right direction. For example does this have a name? Any jQuery plugins that might help?

I have tried to recreate this affect using slideUp() and slideDown() but i am unable to get it to do the desired affect. I also tried using accordion but was unable to get that to produce the desired affect.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. Normally, you have to try something, and come show us your code if you're stuck. However, as a hint, I would define the menu as `position:absolute` so it becomes "free" and won't affect anything else when it moves. Then you can animate it by varying the "bottom" property.

Comment: I'd think the `top` or `height` properties would be better. Still, there are lots of examples of bottom-up menus to have a look at.

Comment: One more piece of advice if you want to go the `position: absolute` route: Make sure you wrap the image and your menu in an element that has `position: relative`.  Otherwise, the menu will just position according to the nearest non-static element, which could be as far up as the whole viewport.

Comment: Yeah sorry. Thanks for your response though, I will play around with absolute positioning and see what i can do. I think this is gonna help me solve this issue so thanks very much - i will also have a look at bottom-up menus, cheers for the terminology.

Answer (score 0):

If initially the menu with submit button need to be present at the bottom of the page:

try setting `position: absolute;` and `bottom:0px;` with defined height.

Then for the arrow mark, bind a click event.

In the click event callback function:

Use `jQuery.animate` function and change the height and top properties of css.

Even better if you don't want any animation, just toggle CSS class for the bottom bar.